# Integrating third party OAuth in Microsoft Bot Node Js

Tags: node.js, botframework

I want to integrate login authorization in Microsoft Bot with Node Js. After login the profile data should be fetch from my website.

I got this error in the Node Js console

```
To talk to your bot, open the emulator select "Open Bot"
Running Auth dialog with Message Activity.

 [onTurnError] unhandled error: DialogContextError: /api/botsignin/GetSignInResource does not exist
```

[Screenshot of Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h2Hi.png)

Comment: You need to supply the code you are using and state what you have tried. We can only guess at what is happening which could literally be anything. Have you looked over the [18.bot-authentication](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication) sample or referred to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Caadv2%2Cjavascript), at all?

Comment: I have adready using this library [bot-authentication](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication). But not working this code @StevenKanberg

Comment: Did you go thru the steps for setting up OAuth connection in the configuration blade of your Azure bot? Also, which version of the SDK are you using?